# Append JSON file after specific array index by using shell script

Tags: json, shell, jq

I want to append some content by using shell script.
I have a JSON file *test.json* as below.

```json
{
  "reference": "Json Test",
  "title": {
    "a": "Json Test"
  },
  "components": [
    {
      "reference": "Json Test",
      "type": "panel",
      "content": [
        {
          "link": "abc/123",
          "label": {
            "a": "for test 123 - a",
            "b": "for test 123 - b"
          }
        },
        {
          "link": "abc/456",
          "label": {
            "a": "for test 456 - a",
            "b": "for test 456 - b"
          }
        },
        {
          "link": "abc/789",
          "label": {
            "a": "for test 789 - a",
            "b": "for test 789 - b"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to append the content and output as following by using shell script (*.sh) How can I achieve this ?

```json
{
  "reference": "Json Test",
  "title": {
    "a": "Json Test"
  },
  "components": [
    {
      "reference": "Json Test",
      "type": "panel",
      "content": [
        {
          "link": "abc/123",
          "label": {
            "a": "for test 123 - a",
            "b": "for test 123 - b"
          }
        },
        {
          "link": "abc/101112",
          "label": {
            "a": "for test 101112 - a",
            "b": "for test 101112 - b"
          }
        },
        {
          "link": "abc/456",
          "label": {
            "a": "for test 456 - a",
            "b": "for test 456 - b"
          }
        },
        {
          "link": "abc/789",
          "label": {
            "a": "for test 789 - a",
            "b": "for test 789 - b"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to access the index and add some test string, the below command will replace the original data.

```
jq '.components[].content[1] + { "link" : "test" } ' test.json
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [slice filter](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/StringSlice:.%5B10:15%5D) to extract the head and the tail of the array, then use `+` to concatenate head + the new object + the tail. Finally, use [update-assignment `|=`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:%7C=) to modify the array:

```
.components[].content |= .[0:1] + [{ link: "test" }] + .[1:]
```

If you are planning on using this more often, consider defining a reusable function:

```
def splice($at; $obj): .[0:$at] + [$obj] + .[$at:]; 

.components[].content |= splice(1; {link: "test"})
```

Answer (score 2):

Grab the empty sub-array at position `1` (slicing either by start and end position `.[1:1]`, or by start position and length `.[1:][:0]`), and assign to it your insert value formatted as (single-element) array `[{"link": "test"}]` (as you are assigning to an array after all - add more items to it if you want to add all of them at once). This looks almost like your original attempt:

```bash
jq '.components[].content[1:1] = [{"link": "test"}]' test.json
```

---

For convenience, you can also turn this into an `insertAt` function:

```bash
def insertAt($pos; $val): .[$pos:$pos] = [$val];

.components[].content |= insertAt(1; {"link": "test"})
```

Comment: Slicing to an empty array and then assigning to it? Awesome!